# Rails Scaffold based on existing model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

I want to generate scaffolding based on an existing model using scaffold_controller.

```
rails generate scaffold_controller NAME
```

I only get empty views, I'm not getting the fields defined in the migration. Not sure what is really going on because I use to do this and it use to work all the time in previous projects.

I'm using Rails 3.2.12, is this feature no longer available?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, I think the problem is specific to my Rails installation, not sure what but if you ever get this problem, this is the workaround that I found but requires twitter bootstrap:

```
rails generate scaffold_controller <YOUR_MODEL_NAME>
rails g bootstrap:themed <YOUR_MODEL_NAME> -f
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have attributes in your views, you have pass them into the `generate scaffold_controller` command, like this:

```
generate scaffold_controller <YOUR_MODEL_NAME> attribute1 attribute2 attribute3
```

Then it will create views with just those attributes in them.

Answer (score 0):

Your example uses **scaffold_controller** where as if you would like a model to be created and displayed in your views you should use just scaffold. In the case of your code example:

```
rails generate scaffold_controller NAME
```

This should become:

```
rails generate scaffold NAME
```

You will need to specify your attributes and then run

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Well yes I did that too and with --skip option so it skips the model and migration otherwise it fails which is the equivalent of scaffold_controller.

Comment: this use to work in previous projects but not anymore, not sure why!

Comment: Did this work for you? Can you see the fields in the view now?

Comment: nope it didn't, I don't know what's wrong with my rails setup but I found a workaround. I did rails g bootstrap:themed products -f. After doing the normal empty scaffold and that creates the fields.